# In what sense are solutions to the Dirac equation and solutions to the Laplace equation equivalent in string theory?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, dirac-equation, calabi-yau

I have come across statements like *elementary particles on a Calabi-Yau correspond to harmonic forms* (or to cohomology classes, which is equivalent for a compact Kähler manifold, since every cohomology class contains a unique harmonic form), or *solutions to the Dirac equation correspond to solutions of the Laplace equation*, e.g. in [Yau's popular text](https://www.basicbooks.com/titles/shing-tung-yau/the-shape-of-inner-space/9780465028375/):

> Another special feature of Calabi-Yau manifolds and their geometry in particular is that the solutions to the Dirac equation—in this case, the massless particles—are the same as the solutions to another mathematical formulation known as the Laplace equation, which is considerably easier to work with.

on page 142, or

> Once you determine the cohomology class of a bundle, you can use it to find solutions to the Dirac equation, and generate the matter particles.

on page 217, and also in [Hübsch's bestiary](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/1410) on page 13 several massless fields are listed in relation to cohomology groups/hodge numbers. I think I have seen it elsewhere as well, but I don't remember where.

Since solutions to the Dirac equation are fermions and solutions to the Laplace equation are harmonic forms, I assume this refers to the same situation.

Can anyone give a precise statement, as well as an idea of why this is so, or give a reference? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Some interesting references I found are [Nigel Hitchin - Harmonic Spinors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870874900218)
and [Morgan - The Seiberg Witten Equations](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/5866.html).

From these, I start to get a slight idea of what could be going on, but it's much to vague to answer this question (and maybe mistaken). The Klein-Gordon equation for a massless scalar field is essentially given by the d'Alembertian, which could be seen as an 1+3 Laplacian. Dirac contructed his operator to be a kind of a square root of the Klein-Gordon operator. Since the Dirac operator is self-adjoint, its kernel and that of its square, the "Laplacian", are equal. Of course this is very imprecise (for one thing the Klein-Gordon operator and the Dirac operator are defined on different spaces), I wonder if it could be made precise.

Comment: Which page? Sounds like the idea of supersymmetry.

Comment: @Qmechanic edited to include the exact quotations and page numbers. Could you elaborate on the relation to supersymmetry? Thanks!